# Java code is not working properly what i can do?

Tags: java

```
class java
{
public static void main(String args[])
 {
 System.out.println("Testing");
 }
}`
```

not working above code and explain the above method.
`

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it compile? What's the output?

Comment: Don't call your class `java`!

Comment: 1. Write class names with capital letter at the beginning 2. Do not call your class java 3. Read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's cause of `Apostrophe` on the last line of your code.
Plus a class name should always start with a capital letter, jus a bit of information thought it has nothing to do with error.

Your code is trying to print out a line on the console which is `Testing`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the apostrophe at the last line